# Running .exe crashes while running from vs2010 is successful

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I've developed a c++ program using Visual Studio 2010 and it works perfectly, but while trying to start it with the .exe file created in the debug folder instead of inside the VS2010, it crashes. It updates my DB once, but then it crashes unexpectly..

Does anyone know why? What should I do to avoid it in order to be able to run my application in another PC. It uses the winsock library and mysql API for C, so I'm wondering if I need to configure something else that the VS2010 doesn't do by its own while linking or so.

Comment: You should run your exe from a terminal (`Win + R` -> `cmd`) to see if any error is displayed when crashing

Comment: It also crashes at the same point and the system just launches the JIT debugger from VS2010 and the exception is win32 uncontrolled exception with a 4 digit number of exception changing from time to time.

Comment: After it crashes, attach your debugger and you should be able to see what line of code it's on along with a call stack etc.  Failing that, try the old-fashioned approach of littering your code with messages to stdout (or to a log file) to help you narrow down the line of code it's failing on, values of variables, etc.

Comment: Do you get the same result when running from visual studio but without the debugger? Was Ctrl-F5 in older versions.

Comment: *COUGH* DEBUG HEAP *COUGH*

Answer (score 0):

Did you depend on the current directory? We had a case once that turned up where that was the problem.

Comment: I'd say not.. The strange thing I forgot to tell is that it gets to update my DB the first time, but then it crashes...

Comment: What happens if you clear out the database? Something tells me that when reading database records back, your code croaks.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the build configuration to `Release`, and use the .exe from the `Release` folder, once you rebuild the application. The executable from the `Debug` folder is (in principle) only used by Visual Studio internally, and it would therefore make no sense to redistribute it.

Note however, that in order to run any application created with visual C++, the user must install the visual C++ redistributable package, so make sure that the user has got that installed.

Comment: I've also tried with the release version of the executable, but it crashes at the same point. Also, Visual c++ 2010 redistributable is installed in the computer.

Comment: What does it show when you run the program from the command line? Is there a stacktrace or something?